# Combobox Issues System.data.datarowview

Tags: c#

I'm working on a GUI and when I'm pulling information from a SQL database,
I'm having issues with the results. Instead of the information I've requested, I'm getting the following:

[image]

Here is the code i am using:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` from the collection that you are using to bind the combobox. Here you are fetching only the name both the fields can be `"name"` suppose you are taking some `vehicle_id` and `name`, probably `"vehicle_id"` will be the `ValueMember`. So use like this:

```
cbSelectVehicle.ValueMember="name";
cbSelectVehicle.DisplayMember="name";
cbSelectVehicle.DataSource=dt_vehicle;
```

`DisplayMember` is nothing but what we seen in the UI, where as the valueMember is hidden but we can access them through code.

Comment: Awesome You are the best it works Thank you so much.